# Using $_POST in 2 if statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use one post in 2 different if statements.
What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to insert 3 values in mysql with post.

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == "checkCharacterName"){
      $username = $_POST['name'];
}
```

it gets the character name here ^
and then in different action it gets the password:

```
if($action == "registerUser"){
$password = $_POST['password'];
$qry = $db->prepare ( 'INSERT INTO user_data (id, username, password, gold)
                       VALUES (null, "'. $username .'","'. $password .'",      500)');
$qry->execute();
```

but it shows this error:

```
Undefined variable: username
```

The posts are sending through swf, so I'm not able to change it cause its not mine swf

Comment: submit your form code too

Comment: Just one of your `if` statements will trigger for each request. Thus one of the variables will be undefined after. If you want to persist information between requests, use sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You work in PHP. This is a **STATELESS** langage. It means each time you post data, the whole script is executed but NO VARIABLES are saved. There is two ways to bypass this.

- Adding state : Save the $username in the $_SESSION object or in the $_COOKIE object.
- Working stateless : Do your request in only ONE POST. (Sending the username and the password at same time.

[More informations to maintain a state here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch07_06.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much, ill use the $_SESSION.